# Javascript doesn't work for the users except System admin

Tags: javascript

Javascript doesn't work for the users except System admin. I checked in all files. And everyone can view the pages and sites.

How can I solve this?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="">

        jQuery.fn.center = function () {
            this.css("position","absolute"); 
            this.css("top", ( $(window).height() - this.height() ) / 2 + $('#s4-workspace').scrollTop() + "px");    
            this.css("left", ( -300+$(window).width() - this.width() ) / 2 + $(window).scrollLeft() + "px");    
            return this;
        } 

        jQuery.fn.centerleft = function () {
            this.css("position","fixed");    
            this.css("top", ( $(window).height() - this.height() ) / 2 + $('#s4-workspace').scrollTop() + "px");    
            this.css("left", ( -300 + $(window).width() - this.width() ) / 2 + $(window).scrollLeft() + "px");    
            return this;
        } 

        $().ready(function () {
            $('.thumbnailyatay').mouseover(function() {
                $(this).next().center().show();
            }).mouseout(function() {
                $(this).next().hide();
            });

            $('.thumbnaildikey').mouseover(function() {
                $(this).next().centerleft().show();
            }).mouseout(function() {
                $(this).next().hide();
            });
        });
    </script>   
    <style type="text/css">
    .large {
 display:none;
 }



<a class="small" >
<xsl:attribute name="href">
<xsl:value-of select="@BigPicture"></xsl:value-of></xsl:attribute>
<img class="thumbnaildikey" alt="gallery thumbnail" style="width:88px;">
<xsl:attribute name="src">
<xsl:value-of select="@BigPicture"></xsl:value-of></xsl:attribute></img>
<img class="large" alt="gallery thumbnail" style="height:800px;width:568px">
<xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select="@BigPicture">
</xsl:value-of></xsl:attribute></img>
</a>
```

Comment: Could you provide code sample?

Comment: What you mean? Could you provide code sample?

Comment: You need to post the actual javascript.

Comment: I add the codes to the question. Sorry for the late answers

Comment: My problem is changed.

Comment: Try to move your *jquery.js* to style library folder

Comment: It didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you do not have any absolute urls in your javascript. Use server relative URLs only.

Comment: Yes, I did it .

Answer (score 1):

Also ensure that where you are storing the JS files are accessible (site assests or wherever) by all users in terms of permissions etc...

Cheers,

S

Comment: I give read permission to site members. Nothing changed.

Comment: Can i ask where you have the file?

Comment: I found the reason. I removed src="" in the <script type="text/javascript" src="">. Thanks to all of you.